# Hide element with specific css selector in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using the WordPress plugin "restrict content pro".

I would like to hide an element with selector `li#wp-admin-bar-my-account-messages` for a specific subscription id with PHP within my functions.php file.

I guess the PHP validation is `rcp_is_active() && rcp_get_subscription_id() == 2` but don't know how to go on from here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `rcp_is_active() && rcp_get_subscription_id() == 2` will validate to your specific use case and you just want to hide the element which has selector `li#wp-admin-bar-my-account-messages` you can do the following in your function.php

```
if ( rcp_is_active() && rcp_get_subscription_id() == 2 )
{
    // for frontend
    add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">li#wp-admin-bar-my-account-messages{display:none !important}</style>';
    } );

    // for backend
    add_action( 'admin_head', function() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">li#wp-admin-bar-my-account-messages{display:none !important}</style>';
    } );
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Danke :D 

Thank you alot! you saved me after hours of searching.